# Trying to create a general search using django filters for all the fields in a given model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

So I am creating a custom filter for my model and I want all the fields in that filter not use 'exact' but 'contains', but I don't want to manually add all the fields. I am trying to do something like this:

```
from django_filters import FilterSet
from polls.models import Question, Choice
from django_filters import rest_framework

class ChoiceFilter(FilterSet):
    for field in Choice._meta.get_fields():

        field = rest_framework.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    #question = rest_framework.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains') #this works want to generalize this

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = '__all__'
```

So the second line works, but my for loop doesn't and my filter uses 'exact' instead of 'contains'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `FilterSet` class which overrides the `get_fields` method to change the lookups from `exact` to `icontains`:

```
class CustomFilterSet(FilterSet):
    @classmethod
    def get_fields(cls):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        for name, lookups in fields.items():
            lookups[:] = ['icontains']
        return fields
```

Now you simply make `ChoiceFilter` inherit from this class:

```
class ChoiceFilter(CustomFilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = '__all__'
```

Keep in mind it's considered dangerous to use `__all__` for fields.

Comment: Thank you! this seems to mostly work, I am just getting an error that says 'django_filters.exceptions.FieldLookupError: Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for field 'polls.Choice.question'.'. I am fairly sure the error is because 'question' is a foreign Key, do you know how I could possibly solve that?

Comment: You are correct. You will either need to explicitly state all fields or use [exclude](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filterset.html#exclude) to exclude the `question` field.

Comment: Do you know of a way of getting all foreign keys in a model in say a list? (Never mind I can do that search on my own, but thank you very much!)

Comment: For this you can use the [`get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) method, but it's not recommended. If you ever add new fields to your `Choice` model your `ChoiceFilterSet` is implicitly changed.

Comment: Do you think something like this would work?        ` blackList = []
        for field in Choice._meta.fields:
            if field.get_internal_type() == 'ForeignKey':
                blackList.append(field.__name__)

        exclude = blackList`

Comment: @ikkuh I've seen the comment about `__all__` being dangerous in a few answers, but haven't seen an explanation. Couldn't find it in Django filter docs either. Why is it not a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

In my use-case I needed to filter a single DateTimeField by several lookup expressions all based on date. The most efficient way was to use the *date__* prefix inside my fields dict:

```
# Bullet Filter
class BulletFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Bullet
        fields = {
            'bullet_header': ['icontains'],
            'bullet_cite_date': ['iexact', 'gte', 'lte'],
            'created': ['date__iexact', 'date__gte', 'date__lte'],
            'updated': ['date__iexact', 'date__gte', 'date__lte'],
        }
```

Here *bullet_header* is a CharField, *bullet_cite_date* is a DateField, and *created* and *updated* are DateTimeFields.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from django-filter v2.3, you could just define `FILTERS_DEFAULT_LOOKUP_EXPR = 'icontains'` in your `settings.py`, which will change the default behavior.